# upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 - ubuntu locks me out of the ui for brief bursts

Tags: cron, gui

It feels like I no longer get ui events or can click anything. like there is an invisible window between me and all applications. I can get out of it by hitting the windows key and re-selecting any app.

I am running `tail -f /var/log/syslog` on my third monitor and I do not see a strong correlation between any events there and the freezes.
The last two were related to CRON jobs of some sort:

```
Jan 27 23:17:01 AypahyosComputer CRON[79647]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

Jan 27 23:30:01 AypahyosComputer CRON[80218]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
```

Not sure what to make from it.

This may be interesting for other users since it happened as a consequence to a recent update.

Any Ideas how I could further narrow the cause down?

EDIT: Hand another freeze while moving a window from screen 1 to screen 2

```
Jan 27 23:54:20 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (58371975) is greater than comparison timestamp (58371581).  This most likely represents a buggy client sending inaccurate timestamps in messages such as _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW.  Trying to work around...
Jan 27 23:54:20 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: Window manager warning: 0x240000a appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 58371975.  Working around...
Jan 27 23:54:20 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x56495d472370] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 27 23:54:20 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x56495d87dee0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 27 23:54:20 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x56495f8e6350] is on because it needs an allocation.
```

EDIT: next freeze while opening the terminal

```
Jan 27 23:58:17 AypahyosComputer systemd[2235]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Jan 27 23:58:17 AypahyosComputer systemd[2235]: Started VTE child process 82078 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 72869.
```

EDIT: this freeze looks interesting because it went hand in hand with exceptions

```
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: Object .Gjs_ui_workspaceThumbnail_ThumbnailsBox (0x56496dcc9bd0), has been already disposed — impossible to get any property from it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: == Stack trace for context 0x56495cf62180 ==
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #0   7ffe8950d7f0 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspacesView.js:639 (2cdd8055bf10 @ 33)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #1   7ffe8950d940 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspacesView.js:686 (2cdd8055bfb0 @ 488)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #2   56495f671038 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:855 (2cdd805072e0 @ 370)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #3   56495f670fb0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:806 (2cdd80507240 @ 17)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #4   7ffe895118b0 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspacesView.js:1016 (2cdd8055ca10 @ 124)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #5   56495f670f20 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overviewControls.js:715 (64cadfbcc40 @ 39)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #6   56495f670e98 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/layout.js:347 (1ede62830510 @ 22)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #7   56495f670e08 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overview.js:586 (64cadfbaab0 @ 170)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #8   56495f670d88 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overview.js:564 (64cadfbaa60 @ 12)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #9   56495f670d08 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overviewControls.js:753 (64cadfbcd80 @ 55)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #10   7ffe89514d80 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:151 (1ede628cc4c0 @ 39)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #11   7ffe895154a0 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:317 (1ede628cc9c0 @ 14)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: == Stack trace for context 0x56495cf62180 ==
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #0   7ffe8950d940 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspacesView.js:688 (2cdd8055bfb0 @ 505)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #1   56495f671038 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:855 (2cdd805072e0 @ 370)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #2   56495f670fb0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:806 (2cdd80507240 @ 17)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #3   7ffe895118b0 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspacesView.js:1016 (2cdd8055ca10 @ 124)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #4   56495f670f20 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overviewControls.js:715 (64cadfbcc40 @ 39)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #5   56495f670e98 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/layout.js:347 (1ede62830510 @ 22)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #6   56495f670e08 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overview.js:586 (64cadfbaab0 @ 170)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #7   56495f670d88 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overview.js:564 (64cadfbaa60 @ 12)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #8   56495f670d08 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overviewControls.js:753 (64cadfbcd80 @ 55)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: Object .Gjs_ui_workspaceThumbnail_ThumbnailsBox (0x56496dcc9bd0), has been already disposed — impossible to get any property from it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #9   7ffe89514d80 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:151 (1ede628cc4c0 @ 39)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #10   7ffe895154a0 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:317 (1ede628cc9c0 @ 14)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: Object St.Button (0x56496868eeb0), has been already disposed — impossible to get any property from it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: Object St.Label (0x56496d4fc400), has been already disposed — impossible to get any property from it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: == Stack trace for context 0x56495cf62180 ==
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #0   56496d453018 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowPreview.js:566 (2cdd8050b420 @ 10)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: == Stack trace for context 0x56495cf62180 ==
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #0   56496d453018 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowPreview.js:567 (2cdd8050b420 @ 36)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: == Stack trace for context 0x56495cf62180 ==
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: #0   56496d453018 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowPreview.js:570 (2cdd8050b420 @ 77)
Jan 28 00:15:33 AypahyosComputer gnome-shell[2424]: Object .Gjs_ui_windowPreview_WindowPreview (0x5649686cbc20), has been already disposed — impossible to get any property from it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
```

EDIT: interesting error about nvidia while freeze happened

```
Jan 28 00:55:02 AypahyosComputer kernel: [62015.480275] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 515.86.01, but
Jan 28 00:55:02 AypahyosComputer kernel: [62015.480275] NVRM: this kernel module has the version 470.161.03.  Please
Jan 28 00:55:02 AypahyosComputer kernel: [62015.480275] NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
Jan 28 00:55:02 AypahyosComputer kernel: [62015.480275] NVRM: components have the same version.
```

I will make sure my nvidia driver components are up to snuff and see if that makes the errors disappear.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like removing all of nvidia and reinstalling the nvidia drivers is what fixed those freezes.